# How to make individual URL for every page in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, settings

I have an old version of phpmyadmin, which was correctly configured by someone I don't know. 
In those version, then you browse pages in php my admin, for each page generate personal, individual URL in browser url box.
So, for example, if I make a SQLquery from phpmyadmin, I can copy URL of the page with results and send to someone.

Now I have newly installed phpmyadmin 3.4.3.2, and then I browse page in this, I always have link, that looks like something like this

http://192.168.4.194/Tools/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=DataBaseName&token=aa39e654e0e646f3b8c809d4cb28f3b2

and this link is for every page I tried (excluding token, which changes time to time)

Is there a setting to change page URL behavior to something, I have in old version?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called url rewriting. To achieve this you need to add *.htaccess* in root folder of phpMyAdmin installation and add following code to it..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path_to_phpMyAdmin
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-z_]+\.php)$ index.php?db=$1&table=$2&target=$3 [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-z_]+\.php)$ index.php?db=$1&target=$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?db=$1&table=$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?db=$1 [R]
```

Don't forget to replace the `path_to_phpMyAdmin` in the above code with your own directory path. For details visit [this link](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#faq1_34).